# Why does ArrayList.add() call ArrayList.grow() without exceeding ArrayList.size()?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, benchmarking, jmh

EDIT2: rephrasing the question due to more details.

This got me curious. Profiling this code:

```java
public class ProfilerTest {
    private static int loops = 1_000_000_000;
    private static int listSize = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
            var list = new ArrayList<Integer>(listSize);
            for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++) {
                list.add(j);
            }
            assert list.size() == listSize;
        }
    }
}
```

Profiler says `grow()` gets called by `add(Object)`. Looking at the source, my JDKs implementation of `ArrayList.add(Object)` calls this helper:

```java
private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

which should only call `grow()` when *exceeding* the size (`s`).

Even when I increase the `initialCapacity` to `2*listSize`, `grow()` gets called. What am I missing here?

---

### original question:

I have found through profiling, that one of my methods is sometimes calling `ArrayList.grow()`. The thing is, the method should not call `grow()` at all since I know the desired size. Modifications to the size can happen in other methods though.

Surprised by this, I did a little benchmark. <s>The results seem strange to me. Not only is `MatchingCapacity` performing much worse, its variability is also much higher, at least for small sizes, which, in my use case are the most common.</s>

The questions I have:

- Is it really possible java calls `grow()` when you fill an ArrayList to its exact amount, or might that just be due to profiler inaccuracies (i.e. subroutine calls `grow()` but sometimes ends up getting measured in parent caller?)
- <s>why is `initialCapacity` slower in the benchmark, is it somehow breaking java compiler optimizations?</s>

unfortunately I am getting an error when trying to profile the JMH benchmark for more insights..

EDIT: as was pointed out in the comments I was reading the numbers all wrong, assuming I was looking at time instead of throughput, so the remaining question is about the profiler.

```java
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
@Warmup(iterations = 1, time = 3)
@Measurement(iterations = 3, time = 3)
@Fork(value=2)
public class PerformanceTest {
    private int size = 30;

    @Benchmark
    public ArrayList<Integer> MatchingCapacity() {
        var list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public ArrayList<Integer> MismatchingCapacity() {
        var list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public ArrayList<Integer> OversizedCapacity() {
        var list = new ArrayList<Integer>(size + size/2);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public ArrayList<Integer> DefaultCapacity() {
        var list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

```
# JMH version: 1.35
# VM version: JDK 17.0.3.1, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6

size=3
PerformanceTest.DefaultCapacity      thrpt    6  37681589.763 � 10696982.725  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MatchingCapacity     thrpt    6  54285199.864 � 20674575.714  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MismatchingCapacity  thrpt    6  21430358.674 � 11202223.852  ops/s
PerformanceTest.OversizedCapacity    thrpt    6  50519838.911 � 19575866.550  ops/s

size=30
PerformanceTest.DefaultCapacity      thrpt    6  4253362.573 �  120027.530  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MatchingCapacity     thrpt    6  8071248.285 � 5138133.875  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MismatchingCapacity  thrpt    6  5108706.433 �  562235.033  ops/s
PerformanceTest.OversizedCapacity    thrpt    6  6867041.239 � 5561825.025  ops/s

size=300
PerformanceTest.DefaultCapacity      thrpt    6  466885.040 � 486083.752  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MatchingCapacity     thrpt    6  693234.753 � 268499.890  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MismatchingCapacity  thrpt    6  644182.306 � 324785.510  ops/s
PerformanceTest.OversizedCapacity    thrpt    6  773775.315 �  26808.161  ops/s

size=3000
PerformanceTest.DefaultCapacity      thrpt    6  58673.411 � 23803.125  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MatchingCapacity     thrpt    6  64863.127 � 33194.262  ops/s
PerformanceTest.MismatchingCapacity  thrpt    6  58921.951 � 21346.733  ops/s
PerformanceTest.OversizedCapacity    thrpt    6  62658.432 � 32061.866  ops/s
```

Comment: Have you tried `return IntStream.range(0, size).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`? And are you sure this is the critical path of your project? Because I doubt it.

Comment: "Matching capacity is performing much worse" – but is it? Only for size=300 it seems to be a bit slower than "Oversized capacity", for all other sizes it has the highest throughput. I'd add GC metrics to the profile, to see how many bytes are allocated per benchmark.

Comment: @knittl oh lord, yes you are absolutely right. I forgot I switched from time to throughput :') thanks

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no I have not, and I am 99% sure it will perform the worst, have been successfully replacing Stream-one-liners with "uglier" loops for performance gain a couple of times in this project.

Comment: @N4ppeL Are you sure about performance gains? Because yes, the first resolution of the `invokedynamic` instruction takes a slow path; but subsequent calls should be optimized. Also, what version of the JVM are you testing here? Because I bet that matters more than these micro-optimizations.

Comment: Your edit to the question seems to have removed the part the title was about, but you haven't changed the title.  So as it stands now, the title makes no sense for the question you're asking.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes I measured quite thoroughly and execution time improved almost 10% for just ONE replacement of streams vs loop. 10% is quite noticeable for an average case runtime of 8 minutes. You know, just to prove a point I added your solution and ran it with `size=3000` and got `44872.716 �  7326.157  ops/s` :)

Comment: Regarding your latest edit: when you want to set the value at index `s` of array `elementData` and `s` is equal to `elementData.length`, then you'd be trying to access the index *after* the last element and get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Generally speaking: if you think you found a glaringly obvious off-by-one error in a heavily used and tested class like `ArrayList` then chances are that you didn't.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the thing is, `elementData.length` should never be <= s in that code, should it? Initializing the list with `initialCapacity` directly sets `elementData = new Object[initialCapacity]`

Comment: I don't think I found an error, at this point I am just curious how this works :)

Comment: `grow()` might be called due to *some other* use of `ArrayList` *anyhwere* in the tons of Java code that runs before control ever even reaches your `main` method. But your `main` method will not cause `grow()` to be called on `list`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer no, not really, at least if I can trust my profiler. It says: `ProfilerTest.main(String[])` calls `j.u.ArrayList.add(Object)` calls `j.u.ArrayList.add(Object, Object[], int)` calls `j.u.ArrayList.grow()`, calls `j.u.ArrayList.grow(int)` and uses between 7 and 15% time of `main`s time. My current guess would be something like branch prediction... which is kinda hard to prove / disprove

Comment: @N4ppeL: put blundly: I don't trust that your profiler actually tells you what you think it tells you. See my answer for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your sample **does not** cause the internal `elementArray` to be resized for the `ArrayList`s referenced by `list`. To demonstrate that, I've used nasty reflection tricks to look into `list`:

```
private static final int LOOPS = 1_000_000;
private static final int LIST_SIZE = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Field elementData = ArrayList.class.getDeclaredField("elementData");
    elementData.setAccessible(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < LOOPS; i++) {
        var list = new ArrayList<Integer>(LIST_SIZE);
        var initialLength = ((Object[]) elementData.get(list)).length;
        for (int j = 0; j < LIST_SIZE; j++) {
            list.add(j);
        }
        var endLength = ((Object[]) elementData.get(list)).length;

        if (initialLength != endLength) {
            throw new Exception("array was resized!");
        }
        if (list.size() != LIST_SIZE) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected list size!");
        }
    }
}
```

This needs to be run with `--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED` on recent JDKs, since it's doing ugly stuff that no production code should do.

What it does however is demonstrate that the `elementData` of the `list`has the same size before and after adding objects to it.

Comment: nice one, I like this. It doesn't explain why the profiler measures it, but it shows it's not executed... making it more likely that perhaps the profiler measures code loaded but not executed, due to branch prediction.

Comment: I think "branch prediction" is a red herring here. AFAIK that should never be visible in the profiler (outside of slower-than-expected times for some method, perhaps). I suggest you post a **new** question about why you see that method there with all the necessary details (such as which profiler and which settings you are using)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. The method `ArrayList.grow(int)` is called when needed.

However, your code isn't the only use of ArrayList. Before your main method is run, class loaders run. As part of their implementation, they're using ArrayList.

You can see this happening in a debugger. Set a breakpoint on the first statement in your main() method. When it's hit, then set a breakpoint in `ArrayList.grow(int)`. That breakpoint won't be hit for your code.

Comment: Random aside: IDEA (and probably other IDEs as well) have the neat ability to selectively enable breakpoints only after hitting another specified breakpoint (and if the other breakpoint isn't set up to trigger the debugger you can automagically ignore one breakpoint until some specified point in your code).

Comment: I believe the IDEA profiler wouldn't tell me the method was called by my own code if it actually wasn't. See my latest comment below the question where I mention the profilers stack trace.

Comment: @N4ppeL: I'm almost certain that you are overestimating the fidelity/resolution that your profiler (and/or your specific settings for it) provide you.